# Feature 'interpolated strings' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, string-interpolation

The following line does not compile when I put in a Razor View.

```
var extPropLookupNameCompania = $"extension_{SettingsHelper.ClientId.Replace("-", "")}_{"Compania"}";
```

However in the controller the same line works perfectly fine.

Why I cant user string interpolation on the razor views? or Maybe I need to configure something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are experiencing this error in a .NET Framework 4.5.1 project, upgrading to 4.5.2 solves the problem.

Comment: If the error does not go away, installing the following NuGet package may help.

`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Comment: Here's some detail on the codeDom package: http://dusted.codes/using-csharp-6-features-in-aspdotnet-mvc-5-razor-views

Comment: I'm on .NET Framework 4.6 and I still get this error.

Comment: Real answer is in comments by @omufeed or tlbignerd not in content labeled as answers.

Comment: What worked for me was installing the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Answer (score 3):

You have to encapsulate it with braces like this:

EDIT: I updated because there was a missing curly.

```
var extPropLookupNameCompania = $("{extension_{SettingsHelper.ClientId.Replace("-", "")}_{"Compania"}");
```

I tried the following successfully:

```
 @($"It is {DateTime.Now}")
```

Comment: I get this: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0019 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: I added a curly brace at the beginning. Is it better now? You have to check the thing by yourself. Thats why I added the principle sample.

Comment: nop, that doesnt work, I still get the same error from first comment, your line works perfectly fine, but mine doesnt.

Comment: How about replacing `{"Compania"}`with `{Compania}`?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to see the compilerOptions="/langversion:6 portion of the following in your web.config.  Without it I got errors trying to use string interpolation inside a .cshtml file.

```html
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```