# Unable to use interpolated strings in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, razor, string-interpolation

I am getting this annoying error when trying to use a simple interpolated string in my `cshtml` file:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ppTitles.Count; i++)
{
    <p>@ResourceLibrary.Resources.GetString($"PP_Text_{i + 1}")</p>
}
```

> Feature 'interpolated strings' is not available in C# 5.  Please use language version 6 or greater.

I have tried all of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844056/feature-interpolated-strings-is-not-available-in-c-sharp-5-please-use-languag)

- Got the langversion in `web.config`
- Tried surrounding the string with `@()`
- Upgraded the project to `4.5.2`

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686990/feature-interpolated-strings-is-not-available-in-c-sharp-5-please-use-languag)

- Changed language version from `default` to `6`
- Installed CodeDome with `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

I have used string interpolation in other areas of the project (in regular `.cs` files) without any issue.

What is going on here?

Comment: Check Build => Advanced Build Settings. The target framework already updated, but language version may not be updated to use C# 6 yet (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686990/feature-interpolated-strings-is-not-available-in-c-sharp-5-please-use-languag).

Comment: Which version of VS?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view

Comment: perhaps you should install `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Comment: check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view) It helps for the same isssue

Comment: check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832659/string-interpolation-in-a-razor-view) It helps for the same issue

Comment: @Bassie did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When using `C#` 5 or older, interpolated strings are not available out of teh box and you will be required to install a NuGet package for this to be supported. Note that (as the error states) this is included out of the box in `C#` 6 and up.

You'll need to install the NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` to your web project (or whichever project contains your views)

This package will add support for interpolated strings (as well as improve compilation performance). If the package installation did not add the following to your web.config's configuration, then you'll need to add it in manually:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
```